# How to parse array of hashes (strings)

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"A\"}", "{\"id\":20,\"name\":\"B\"}"]
```

I get this array from redis and I need to iterate and access id and name keys. I really need to call JSON.parse in every iteration ?

How can I iterate and display data ?

Comment: "I really need to call `JSON.parse` in every iteration?" - on every element, yes.

Comment: like this?

`<% visitors.each do |v| %>
    <% visitor = JSON.parse(v) %>`

Comment: This is one way to do this, yes. I'd prefer to not bloat my views with unnecessary logic, and move data preparation elsewhere (controller, for example)

Comment: yes
I did this on a cell:
`def visitors
    @options[:visitors].map { |visitor| JSON.parse(visitor) }
  end`

Comment: _"I get this array from redis"_ – how is it stored in Redis, as a list?

Comment: It's stored as a json using { key: value }.to_json

Comment: @JoaoSilva and each JSON element is stored separately?

Answer (score 1):

First, nothing wrong with a loop:

```
arr = ["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"A\"}", "{\"id\":20,\"name\":\"B\"}"]
arr.map {|raw| JSON.parse(raw) }
```

Now, if for any reason you want to avoid the loop, here is some fun option:

```
arr = ["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"A\"}", "{\"id\":20,\"name\":\"B\"}"]
JSON.parse "[#{arr.join(",")}]"
```

So: join the array with ",", making a string that we put between "[]" - this transform your list of JSON encoded values into a single JSON encoded array.

This being said, again - nothing wrong with a loop.

Comment: good solution Martin, tried that but without the surrounding [] it failed

Comment: Just tried the code in my IRB with your exact example, looks to work:

Comment: iaa you misunderstood, your example works +1 (otherwise wouldn't be good :), I tried it the same way and it failed because of..

Answer (score 0):

On your question if you need to do this with a map method you got the answer allready in the comments and the alternative from Martin.

Here is a way to separate the logic from your view like Sergio suggests

Somewhere in your controller, model or helper file

```
class Visitor
  require 'json'
  def initialize string
    hash = JSON.parse(string)
    @id   = hash["id"]
    @name = hash["name"]
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@id}: #{@name}"
  end
end

class Visitors
  include Enumerable

  @@visitors = []
  def initialize array
    array.map{|visitor| @@visitors << Visitor.new(visitor)}
  end

  def each
    @@visitors.map{|visitor| yield visitor}
  end
end


array = ["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"A\"}", "{\"id\":20,\"name\":\"B\"}"]
visitors =  Visitors.new(array)
```

And in your view

```
visitors.each do |visitor|
  <%=visitor%>
end

# 1: A
# 20: B
```